# Most efficient way to programmatically update and configure forms and controls

Tags: vb.net, winforms, panel, screenupdating

I am looking for a way to prevent user form controls from appearing one by one when I'm programmatically adding them and for ways to enhance application performance and visual appeal.

Say, I have a `Panel_Top` in which I programmatically add comboboxes. What is happening is that they appear one by one as they are created and I am looking for a way to suspend the refreshing of the panel and or user form to make all of those programmatically added comboboxes to appear at the same time and faster than it happens right now.

I've tried `suspendlayout` which doesn't do anything for me or maybe I'm doing it wrong.

```
MyForm.PanelTop.SuspendLayout = true
```

And also I've tried to set the `Panel_Top` to invisible like:

```
MyForm.Top_Panel.visible = false
```

Which kind of sorta looks and performs better, or it might be a placebo.

What is the correct approach to this problem?

PS: I do have form set to `doublebuffer = true`, if that matters

Comment: `MyForm.PanelTop.SuspendLayout = true` **?** You mean `MyForm.PanelTop.SuspendLayout()`. It's a method. Have you tried `MyForm.SuspendLayout()` then `ResumeLayout(false)` after adding the controls? Try it.

Comment: ``MyForm.PanelTop.SuspendLayout()`` still doesn't affect controls appearing one by one

Comment: Please show the code that adds the controls to  the Panel_Top

Comment: ``Public ComboBox_1 as new ComboBox
MyForm.Top_Panel.Controls.Add(ComboBox_1 )``
Basically like that

Answer (score 1):

What I tend to do is create a loading modal to appear on top of the form rendering the controls that need to be created/made visible, this can optionally have a progress bar that gets incremented as the control is created/shown. With the loading modal running, the container that needs to add the controls starts with SuspendLayout, adds the controls, and then finished with ResumeLayout.

This makes it so that controls are added/shown while giving the user a visual indicator that something is going on behind the scenes.

Here is a phenomenal example of a loading modal: https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?869567-Modal-Wait-Dialogue-with-BackgroundWorker and here is an example of using it:

```vb
Private ReadOnly _controlsToAdd As New List(Of Control)()

Private Sub MyForm_Show(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
    Using waitModal = New BackgroundWorkerForm(AddressOf backgroundWorker_DoWork,
                                               AddressOf backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged,
                                               AddressOf backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted)
        waitModal.ShowDialog()
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub backgroundWorker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    Dim worker = DirectCast(sender, BackgroundWorker)
    For index = 1 To 100
        _controlsToAdd.Add(New ComboBox() With {.Name = $"ComboBox{index}"})
        worker.ReportProgress(index)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(100) ' Zzz to simulate a long running process
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs)
    Dim percentageCompleted = e.ProgressPercentage / 100
    ' do something with the percentageCompleted value
End Sub

Private Sub backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
    PanelTop.SuspendLayout()
    PanelTop.Controls.AddRange(_controlsToAdd.ToArray())
    PanelTop.ResumeLayout()
End Sub
```

Comment: Controls should only be created on a GUI Thread.

Comment: @LarsTech - I suppose I am creating them outside of the GUI thread, but they are not being added until the worker is completed.

Comment: Yes, the Controls are created in the UI Thread, but it's not clear why you're using a BackGroundWorker to generate just the instances, since the Controls are then created in the UI Thread anyway. Maybe you wanted to show how to offload the work that fills these Controls to a background Thread / Task? A ComboBox won't fill its Items collection until it has a handle (PInvoking the native Control)

Comment: @Jimi It is to demonstrate the control creation in an asynchronous manner, providing the user with a loading indicator that the controls are being created, and then adding the created controls all at once.

Comment: As you also mentioned, the Controls are created in the UI Thread. So, *synchronously* in any case. What helps the Form's layout procedure is calling `.SuspendLayout()` and `.ResumeLayout(false)`. BUT, in relation to the OP, these Controls are *probably not empty*, hence it's probably the procedure that fills them that causes some delay. The `SuspendLayout()` / `ResumeLayout()` calls may solve part of the issue by themselves. Otherwise, it's the work related to retrieving the data that fills the ComboBoxes that needs to be offloaded (creating the instance is a breeze)

Comment: @Jimi - I don't understand. I'm not creating the controls in the UI thread. I am creating them in the DoWork event of the BackgroundWorker. This would make the control creation asynchronous. The `Threading.Thread.Sleep` that I have is used to simulate a long running task, like fetching data from a database to populate the control.

Comment: Nope, the Instance is created in DoWork, but the Control is actually created in the UI Thread, when you add it to a Parent container. Try with a Custom Control and override `OnHandleCreated()` and `OnCreateControl()`, see when these methods are actually called

Comment: Ok, so then that is my misunderstanding about how controls are created, but I still don't understand what is wrong with my example.

Comment: Yes, my controls in this case are comboboxes, but I also have a panel with other panels and thsi doesn't seem to make any difference in either cases

Comment: The *wrong* (if you want to call it that) thing is that, as I've previously mentioned, just creating the Instance of the Control is not something that needs any *special procedure* (even less a BackGroundWorker), because it's just that, an allocation. Also, the Control is actually created in the UI Thread anyway and that's when it's actually filled. The *heavy* part, what may cause the Controls to show up at a *slow pace*, is the procedure that fills them with data. That's the part that should be, most probably, addressed -- I.e., this all method is not really useful. Maybe harmful

Comment: @Jimi - That is what I am getting at. You are saying that the method is harmful, but not explaining how. In fact my RunWorkerCompleted does something very similar to Joel's example, but I would argue my example is better because it is using AddRange over Add. I just want to know A) How is my example harmful and B) What could I being differently?

Comment: 1) This method is redundant (read *useless* in practice, I've already explained what's the reason for that) 2) The Instance of a .NET Control is created in an IAsyncOperation procedure. Not exactly a *thread*, but a procedure that doesn't have a synchronixzation context. i.e., not relatable to the UI Thread. You're just creating the Instance here (so, not the real Control), but suppose that someone thinks this can actually be done this way and does something that causes the creation of the Control in the DoWork Handler, as asking for the Control's Handle. Then, what happens?

Comment: 3) Most important (in relation to this post), you're not addressing the real problem, which of course is not the creation of the instances of these Controls -- Using `AddRange()` or `For Each x in y` in a `SuspendLayout()` / `ResumeLayout()` block is the same thing (what is `AddRange()` doing, after all?)

Answer (score 1):

**`SuspendLayout()` is the correct way to handle this with WinForms.**

But first of all, this is a *function you call*, and not a flag you set.

Secondly, don't forget to call `ResumeLayout()` at the end of the changes.

Finally, you need to ensure you only call them **once** when you start to change around the controls in the panel and then again at the very end. If you use them with every control you won't get any benefit.

So the pattern might look something like this:

```
Public Sub SomeMethod()
    PanelTop.SuspendLayout() ' Prevent the panel from updating until you've finished

    ' Make a bunch of changes
    PanelTop.Controls.Clear()
    For Each ...
        PanelTop.Controls.Add( ... )
    Next 

    PanelTop.ResumeLayout() ' Allow the panel to show all the changes in the same WM_PAINT event
End Sub
```

You also need to ensure you don't have anything in there like `DoEvents()`/`Invalidate()` that might invoke the windows message loop and cause the form to redraw itself.

Comment: Yup, that makes sense and that's exactly the logic I'm doing and this doesn't seem to make any difference, I will double check though :) I'm used to this logic when I was doing Excel ``screenupdating = false`` or whatever it was, but in VB.NET this doesn't seem to work as easily